# How to handle incoming share content in capacitor on Android

Tags: android, vue.js, capacitor, quasar-framework

I´m new to android development and I´m currently writing my first Capacitor Android app (with Quasar/Vue) and I want to the app to be able to receive files/images shared from other apps. So far I found out how to register my app as a share target (from here [1])

In Android Manifest I do:

```xml
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name="org.cordova.MYAPP.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            ...

        </activity>
```

So far so good. My app now shows up as a target in the share menu for image files. Touching the icon for my app in that share menu launches my app correctly.

But now I can´t figure out how to handle the incoming intent. The Android documentation [2] suggests to use the `getIntent()` Java API but I don´t know how to translate that into Capacitor. The Capacitor documentation is pretty lightweight in that regard [3]

How can I receive incoming intent calls with Capacitor and handle the data in my Quasar/Vue app? Is that the right way to think about it?

Any pointers are appreciated! Thx

[1] https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive
[2] https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#handling-content
[3] https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/share/

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this post now, I'm using this Cordova plugin:
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith

if you managed to find a native ionic solution please share.